# Problemas con Brew en Rapache

Tags: apache, r, apache2

Buenas, recientemente he instalado rapache en ubuntu server 14.04, realizo todas las configuraciones y creo el archivo r.conf y r.load en /etc/apache2/mods-available. Dentro de r.conf coloco

SetHandler r-script
 RHandler sys.source

Y hago algo similar para el RApacheInfo, esto funciona bien ya que si coloco un archivo con codigo r en la ruta establecida me lo le como codigo r y muestra su salida en el navegrador.

El problema esta con el paquete brew, para este coloco lo siguiente en r.conf

SetHandler r-script
 RHandler brew::brew

y coloco en esa carpeta codigo html, y codigo r de esta forma(<% dodigo en R %>), pero cuando lo ejecuto en el navegador solo interpreta el html, el codigo r sale tal cual.
Nota: ya instale brew mediante > install.package("brew"), que debe hacer para que lea ambos códigos y como puedo fusionar paquetes, es decir que no los tenga que abrir en directorios independientes.

Gracias